# JMETER store request JSON Element as variable

Tags: json, variables, request, jmeter

Trying to figure out how I can access elements of a post request body (JSON) and store it as a variable. One of my tests creates a user using ${__UUID}@gmail.com - and I'd like to then check that my response includes this same information.

I'm guessing I could probably create the UUID before the request and store it as a variable, and then check against that, but wondering if there is anything similar to JSON Path Extractor for request elements.

Comment: you should provide example of request and response to make this question answerable

Answer (score 0):

There is a [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) you can use to fulfil your requirement.

1. Assuming you have JSON Payload like:

   ```
   {
     "user": "${__UUID}@gmail.com"
   }
   ```

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request JSON]
2. Add JSR223 PostProcessor and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def user = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue(), '$..user').get(0).toString()
   log.info('Random user email:' + user)
   vars.put('user', user)
   ```
3. The above code will:

   - Extract from the request everything which matches `$..user` [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression
   - Print it to *jmeter.log* file
   - Store the value into a JMeter Variable so you will be able to refer it as `${user}` where required.

     [image: JMeter JSON Path extract value from the request]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)